# Cant see HAXM in Android Studio in extras or otherwise

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm, android-sdk-manager

I just recently installed Android Studio and I was going through Android Tutorials of New Boston when he said to Open up SDK manager. Go to Extras and look for Intel Accelerator Emulator AKA HAXM installer. 
I did as asked. My version was a newer one so I had to open the "Stand-Alone-SDK-Manager". And as I did.. I scrolled down to the extras. There I only could see "Google Repository".

Nothing else was in the Extras. 
I tried downloading again. Didnt work. I also read a few answers of how to download and patch externally but it didnt work out.

[image]

```
      I have attached the SDK manager's screen.
```

Please help. Thanks in advance. I tried downloading it again from the official site as before. Still the same.

Comment: I forgot to mention but it is a little obvious. 
I am looking to install HAXM installer that isn't present in the SDK MANAGER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get it from somewhere else as well. For example:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Comment: I got it from there. but it didnt work. I Checked again around a week ago and I say there was an update to android studio. when I ugraded it, There it shows the installer and everything else. 
Thank you, though. You're reply helped. I am really sorry, for replying so late.